# Firebase user_pseudo_id vs installation id

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using firebase together with bigquery integration. In the table exported by firebase, I got user_pseudo_id. But if I want to use [Imported Segments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/import-segments?authuser=0#segmentmemberships), it asks for instance_id.

[This doc](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en) says user_pseudo_id can be installation id, together with other possibilities. But it is pretty vague and doesn't say what other possibilities are.

So in short, are user_pseudo_id and instance_id the same? Or rather, can the user_pseudo_id exported by firebase be used as instance_id when we using Import Segments function?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The `user_pseudo_id` field is not initialized by Firebase/Analytics by default, and is whatever you set it to.

If the user signs into your app, it is common to set `user_pseudo_id` to the user ID of the sign-in provider (for example, to the UID of Firebase Authentication). If the users don't sign in to the app, using the instance ID is a common alternative.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen. A followup question, will the Import Segment function use the same id? If not, then it's actually harmful to set `user_pseudo_id` other than instance ID, right? Because we can't use functionalities like A/B testing from firebase out-of-the-box.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was helpful. Based on the info, we in the end decided to step aside from Import Segment function. I had the impression that there's some mis-alignment in the functionalities of BigQuery export and Import Segment, they use different ids. Do you know any successful application that combines these two? Or rather how should Import Segment being used, where should we get the required ids? That would be very helpful.

Comment: @Frank I think you are mixing up `user_pseudo_id` with `user_id`. Actually `user_id` is optional and can be set by users, in the other side`user_pseudo_id` is always present and dependant on the device/app/user combination.

Comment: @Tano: Can you please post an alternative answer in that case? That way, OP can accept your answer - and I can delete this one (which is currently not possible, since it's accepted).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I posted an alternative anwer.

Answer (score 4):

In the Firebase documentation they always speak about `Firebase Installation ID` and not `user_pseudo_id` (or als @dong-wang pointed out in the docs also mentioned as app-instance-id). Plase check these link below how to get this ID and you can send it as **user property** within your events.

[image]
[Go To Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#retrieve_client_identifiers)

#### Clarification about other Firebase IDs:

- `user_id` is a custom ID set by users to identify the same user across different devices.
- `user_pseudo_id` is set by Firebase library and identifies one combination of device/app/user. Same app instance will always delivers the same `user_pseudo_id` to Firebase backend.